# Can a Windows job determine a file version on a Linux system?

Tags: linux, windows

Working on InstallShield installer.  Putting down exes on Windows that will attempt to make contact with a daemon on Centos 7.  The version of the windows files must be the same version as the Linux Daemom.

Is there a way, from the Windows side, to determine the version of the file on the Linux side?

I understand that files on Linux have no versions?  Possibly use ssh to read a txt file that has info in it?  Can someone provide example of script to do this?

Comment: Can you connect to the daemon and have it report its version? That'd be better than connecting over a side channel like SSH. It would decouple the two machines: you wouldn't have to have credentials on the other machine; the Windows machine wouldn't have to know how to interoperate with Linux; heck, it wouldn't even have to *be* a Linux machine.

Comment: I ask that a few minutes ago.  While eventually, the agent should be able to work with all prior versions of the Daemon, right now it only works with the same version, and currently there is no passing back version info.

Comment: Do you control the daemon? See if you can do it the right way now and have the daemon start reporting its version number. Otherwise "currently" will turn into "forever" and you'll forever be doing a janky check over SSH. (At least, based on my professional experience!)

Comment: I am a contract InstallShield developer, I have nothing to do with the product development.  I have advised them that this should be done.  I am half way thru Udemy Linux Admin course, so I do'nt even know yet if all daemons have a version #, do they?